# Change border groove second color?

Tags: html, css

I'm using border groove but I need to edit the second color.

```
border-right: 2px groove #FFFFFF;
border-top: 2px groove #FFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need some CSS trick to make like `groove` style, see this:http://jsfiddle.net/LbH92/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="border">
Hi I have two border colors<br />I am also Fluid
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.border{
    border-right:2px solid #ffffff;
    border-top:2px solid #cccccc; 
    position:relative;
}
div.border:before{
    position:absolute; 
    display:block; 
    content:''; 
    border-right:2px solid #cccccc;
    border-top:2px solid #ffffff; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: 
    border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: 
    border-box;
    }
```

Hope will solve problem!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't change the second color of a groove border.
You should make two different borders using :after.

Answer (score -2):

```
border-top: 2px groove #ff0000;
```

use this code